# DateTime.FromOADate vs MSSQL Cast as DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, datetime

I assumed that **DateTime.FromOADate in .NET** and **casting to a DateTime in MS SQL** worked the same way.

However, given the **value**: **41640**
**DateTime.FromOADate**(value) returns: **2014-01-01**
**CAST**(value **AS DATETIME**) returns: **2014-01-03**

Is this expected behaviour because of different starting days, or is something not right?

Comment: Thank you for being here first; I'm getting the exact. Same. Number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the  **third day** of January in 2014 in T-SQL:

```
SELECT CAST(41640 AS DATETIME)
```

and this is the  **first day** of January in  2014 in .NET:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(41640)
```

The reason is documented in MSDN:

[`CAST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

The "zero"-date is **1900-01-01**

[`DateTime.FromOADate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx)

base date, midnight, **30 December 1899**

So there is a two days difference between  `01/01/1900` and `12/30/1899`.

Answer (score 2):

To investigate this you have to look into the base date first,

In MSSQL `print CAST(0 AS DATETIME)` will output:

> Jan  1 1900 12:00AM

In C# .Net `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.FromOADate(0));` will output:

> 12/30/1899 12:00:00 AM

So you can see there are **2 days** of difference between 2 base date. That's why you are facing such problem.

Answer (score 1):

OLE Automation Dates (aka "OADates") are for compatibility with COM interfaces, and used in communicating to things like Microsoft Excel through VBA.  You shouldn't use them in communicating with SQL Server.  Just return the native SQL `date`, `datetime`, or `datetime2` type in your query and cast it to a `DateTime` in your .NET code.

```
DateTime dt = (DateTime) myDataReader["FooDateTime"];
```

As others have mentioned, the SQL Server epoch is not the same as the OLE Automation epoch.  OLE Automation dates also have some quirky behaviors with negative values, and also that dates before March 1st 1900 might  use an epoch of `12/30/1899` or `12/31/1899` depending on which program is using it.  SQL Server uses a fixed epoch of `1/1/1900`.

And like many of Windows and .NET types, the epoch isn't fixed to UTC, so you have to know what contextual time zone information is in play also.  (Though this also occurs with `DateTime` unless you pay attention to the `.Kind` property.)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server's base date is '19000101'; try CASTing 0.

According to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx
FromOADate starts at 1899-12-30