# Convert variant date (FLOAT) to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a table that contains **FLOAT** field from datetime. When I convert this values to `datetime`, there is a two days difference between converted date with correct date. For example:

[image]

But in this [site](https://planetcalc.com/7027/) date convert is correct!!!

[image]

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18960863/4116685), explains why this happens, but what is the solution in SQL Server?

Comment: You need to use the explicit type cast with the correct "zero" date: `select DATEADD(day, 45099, CONVERT(date, '18991230'))`.

Comment: Just subtract two days’ worth from the float when doing conversions?

Comment: You can use the ```SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,'18991230',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)``` to do the opposite

Comment: At a guess this originally came from a badly converted Excel sheet

Comment: @Charlieface Unfortunately no; this is SQL Server code: ```select cast(getdate() as Int)```

Comment: Well I get 45097 for the same date https://dbfiddle.uk/5UHQdtu1

Comment: @Charlieface These values are added from the attendance device in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct the datetime value from the correct "zero" date:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, 45099, CONVERT(date, '18991230'))
```

Your current statement uses implicit data type conversion and adds number of days to the default datetime value `1900-01-01`.